# Most efficient way using regex to parse proxies using C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012

Using Visual Studio and C#, How can I do the best way to parse a given string of downloaded html using regex to retrieve the proxies?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string stringVar { get; set; }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            stringVar = wc.DownloadString("http://somewebsitewithproxies.com/");

            // some regex operation on stringVar here perhaps?

            textBox1.Text = // ???

        }


    }
}
```

I will be using the regex expression:

```
\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[:]\d{1,5}
```

I would like to have the variable 'stringVar' be parsed and the proxies set to textBox1. Would this be easy enough to do within the entire button click?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Would the answer "Yes" satisfy your expectations?

Comment: I'm sorry, actually I would like to know how to do it.

Comment: how to do *what* exactly?

Comment: How to parse the proxies out of the downloaded html and print them within textbox1. Apologies for not being able to be clearer, I can't think of any other way to ask how to take the downloaded html source code and parse the proxies out.

Comment: have you tried to google? Do you seriously think there is no articles about how to fetch a page and use regular expression?

Comment: Yes, I've been Googling all day and saving webpage after webpage of resources to try to help me figure this out. I am new to this, I have some understanding yet I'm still learning and I have to rely on places such as this to ask questions. Believe me I had to think twice before asking my question here because I knew someone like you was going to come along. I'm just looking for a little help, not attitude.

Comment: "I've been Googling all day" --- you must be kidding. "c# fetch page", "c# how to use regex" gives me tons of useful links

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression can be simplified with repetition.  The following code serves the purpose of matching a proxy pattern.

```
string proxyPattern = @"\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}:\d{1,5}";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, proxyPattern);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Comment: @POPOL Thank you for your response. How could I incorporate this into the code I used in my question above? For instance, if the downloaded html source code using DownloadString is set to a variable called 'stringVar', how can I use your example to parse the proxies and set them to textbox1?